# Catching execSync errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

I'm using `execSync` to run a `soffice` command. The issue I'm having is when an error is thrown `execSync` just logs the error to the console there is no way of catching it. I've tried using a `try` `catch` statement but it still just logs the error to the console.

```
function convertToPdf(filepath, destpath) {
  var cmd = 'sofice command';

  try {
    var res = execSync(cmd, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Errors:", e);
  } 

  console.log("res:", res);
}

convertToPdf("test.docx");
```

I run this and get this back:

```
Error: source file could not be loaded
res:
```

Notice how my catch statement is never logged even though an error was clearly thrown but another `Error:` message is logged automatically because I'm not logging that.

Comment: [The manual](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) says "it throws" but only on certain conditions: "If the process times out, or has a non-zero exit code". Do you have any of these?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How can I know if I can't even check the exit code. All it does is log to screen what I posted above

Comment: I'm not a Node guru but documentation suggest that (process time out apart): it's zero if it doesn't throw an error, it's non-zero otherwise (and you can read the status from the error). Since soffice from LibreOffice (assuming you mean that) is a GUI program I wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't return non-zero codes on error. That should be easy to test in most shells. If you tell us what shell you have we can possibly tell you how to read return value from console. And if you tell us the exact `soffice` command and the error you get we might even reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: How did you solve the problem @Rodrigo?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function myExecSync(command, trim = true, cwd = pwd, opts = {}) {
  const ret = execSync(command, { cwd, ...opts }).toString('utf-8');
  return trim ? ret.trim() : ret;
}
```

And write stdio: 'pipe' manually to prevent childprocess.stderr output to the console. like

```
myExecSync(command, true, cwd, { stdio: 'pipe' })
```

Comment: I don't think this solution will work... the `execSync` will throw exception when you call it and the code will not reach the return statement